# why paginator's page's index doesn't change after changing in code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular-material2, typescript2.0

hy, I have paginator:

```
                   <md-paginator [length]="length"
                                  [pageSize]="pageSize"
                                  [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
                                  (page)="pageEvent = $event">
                    </md-paginator>
```

Paginator works only using UI buttons, but I cannot change page's index without reloading the page in code. Nothing of the following works (`mdPaginator` is in the constructor):

```
this.pageIndex = 0;
this.mdPaginator.pageIndex = 0;
this.mdPaginator.previousPage();
```

By the way, I use paginator in `*ngFor` cycle, not table.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the latest Material 2 version.

If you are on a version below `2.0.0-beta.10`, it is a [bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5904). So update to at least that one.

Then, this should work:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MdPaginator } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
})
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('paginator1') paginator1: MdPaginator;

  myFunction() {
    this.paginator1.pageIndex = 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<md-paginator #paginator1
    [length]="100"
    [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</md-paginator>

<button md-button (click)="myFunction()">Paginate</button>
```

In latest Material version replace `MdPaginator` with `MatPaginator` and all HTML `md-` with `mat-`

Answer (score 0):

simply bind the page index.
it is the simplest way to get over it

```
<mat-paginator [length]="pageLength" class="paginator" [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30, pageLength]" (page)="onPaginateChange($event)">
```